# Canvas fillStyle from number

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get my canvas to use a fill style from an array of ARGB integers.

Here is a minimally working example which can be lifted into JSFiddle:

```
var ctx = $('#cv')[0].getContext("2d");
var pal = [0x00000000, 0xff000000, 0xffff0000];

var col = '"#' + (pal[2]&0xffffff).toString(16) + '"';
alert(col);

ctx.fillStyle = col;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

This gives me a black rectangle, and the fillStyle remains `"#000000"`, yet the correct color is alerted.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add the quotes.

This is fine :

```
var col = '#' + (pal[2]&0xffffff).toString(16);
```

As you did it, your were building a string containing quotes.

Comment: Yeah, can't do it too soon though! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [numerical color values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#numerical) to specify a color for `fillStyle`. The `rgb` and `rgba` operators might be helpful with the added benefit of making your intentions more readable and explicit.